# How to change the webservice URL through flashvars

Tags: apache-flex

I am using a webservice deployed on SAP Web Application Server to create some charts. While migrating my FLEX application from dev to QA, I also wish to change the address of my target webservices in flex, so that they access webservices from QA. What I did was add the target server address as a URL parameter and add these URL parameters as flashvars in Flex.

var wsdlUrl= window.location.search.substring(1);
flashvars.serverUrl = wsdlUrl;

Now I try to access the flashvars during declaration of the webservice

```
<fx:Declarations>
<cscustomreportservice:CSCustomReportService 
id="cSCustomReportService" useProxy="false" wsdl="{FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.serverUrl}" 
fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>
...
</fx:Declarations>
```

But the flashvars are somehow not accessible during the declaration time.

Is there any way I can pass the server URL during runtime so that the URL need not be hardcoded in the Flex application in anyway?

Best regards,
Nakul

Comment: Are you doing the set straight away? As part of your application set up? You might be better waiting for applicationComplete to fire, and set the url directly then.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to `<your application path>\src\services`

Inside the services folder, there would be a folder with the service name. Inside this folder, there would be 2 files, among them, open the the one whose name starts with '_' (underscore).

Inside this file, you can modify the link/URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a Custom Config.xml file under the src folder. 
In you application's main.mxml have a static var that is accessible across your application.

```
public static var endpointUrl:String;
```

Make a HTTPService call to the config.xml

```
<mx:HTTPService id="configSrv"
                url="config.xml"
                resultFormat="e4x"
                result="configResultHandler(event)"/>
```

The result Handler will set the value from config.xml to the endPointUrl

```
//For calling the webservice uri end point
        private function configResultHandler(event:ResultEvent):String
        {
            var xml:XML=event.result as XML;
            var endPointURL:String="" + xml..channel.(@id == "endpoint").@endpoint;
            if (endPointURL == "")
            {
                Alert.show("End Point not configured", "Error");
                return null;
            }
            Security.allowDomain(endPointURL);
            return endPointURL;
        }
```

Now in your tag you can invoke the static variable like this

```
<cscustomreportservice:CSCustomReportService id="cSCustomReportService" useProxy="false" wsdl="{Main.endPointURL}" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>
```

Sample config.xml for your reference:

```
 <channels>
    <channel id="endpoint"
             endpoint="http://localhost:8080/myApp/"/>
</channels>
```